# Command line option for PuTTY (Windows) to set action of mouse buttons to xterm?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, putty

As per the title, I'm looking for a command line option which will have the effect of clicking xterm under *"Window > Selection > Control use of mouse"* in the PuTTY configuration window.

I can't see anything in the standard command line options in the PuTTY docs and I'm trying to create a batch file for some users to save them having to create a session in PuTTY that requires the middle mouse button to paste behaviour.

My users are on Windows machines at the moment, so it needs to work for PuTTY in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no command-line options for setting advanced GUI settings in PuTTY.

Your only option is to set respective registry keys.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\MySession]
...
"MouseIsXterm"=dword:00000001
...
```